# select() returns -1 while reading from socket

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++

I'm trying to solve reading from socket timeout problem using `select()`. Unfortunately this function returns `-1` immediatly after getting called. What might be wrong?

```
commStatus communicate( const char * tx, char * rx, const int bufSize , const char * inetAddr, const int port )
{

    commStatus r;
    if (!sockInitialised) initSock();

    if (sockInitialised)
    {
        SOCKET s;
        struct sockaddr_in server;

        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inetAddr);
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons( port );

        if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            std:stringstream d; d <<"Could not create socket : " << WSAGetLastError();
            LogIt(d,Level::Error);
        } else
        {
            if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
            {
                puts("connect error");
                r= commStatus::COMM_NO_TRANSMIT ;
            } else
            {
                int l =strlen(tx)+strlen("DATA ");

                char* dtx ;
                dtx = (char*) calloc(sizeof(char),strlen(tx)+strlen("DATA ") + 1 );

                sprintf(dtx,"DATA %s",tx);

                if( send(s , dtx , strlen(dtx) , 0) < 0)
                {
                    puts("Send failed");
                    r= commStatus::COMM_NO_TRANSMIT;
                } else
                {

                    int recv_size = 0;


                    struct timeval selTimeout;
                    selTimeout.tv_sec = 20;       /* timeout (secs.) */
                    selTimeout.tv_usec = 0;            /* 0 microseconds */
                    fd_set readSet;
                    FD_ZERO(&readSet);
                     #define STDIN_FILENO 0
                    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readSet);//stdin manually trigger reading
                    FD_SET(s, &readSet);//tcp socket
                    int numReady = select(s+1, &readSet, NULL, NULL, &selTimeout);


                    if(numReady > 0)
                    {
                        if((recv_size = recv(s , rx , bufSize ,0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                        {
                            r= commStatus::COMM_NO_RECEIVE;
                        } else
                        {
                            rx[recv_size] = '\0';
                            r= commStatus::COMM_OK;
                        }
                    } else r=commStatus::COMM_NO_RECEIVE;
                }
                free(dtx);
            }
        }
    } else r= commStatus::COMM_NO_TRANSMIT;
return r;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `WSAGetLastError()` after select returns -1? What does it return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're trying to pass `stdin` to Winsock's [`select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Unfortunately, under Windows, `select()` only takes socket handles, not generic file descriptors.

If you were to call `WSAGetLastError()`, you'd probably see that it returns `WSAENOTSOCK`.

Comment: This is exactly what I have in error  - WSAENOTSOCK. I have commented  FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readSet); line. But now select return 1 immediatly but no data was offered for reception yet.

Answer (score 0):

Under C, you can examine the `errno` variable, it should tell you the *specific* problem that caused your error.

Alternatively, you may have the `perror()` function which will give you a readable version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
:
perror ("select");
```

---

If you're under *Windows,* `WSAGetLastError()` will serve as the `errno` variable, with [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) giving the possibilities and explanations:

**WSANOTINITIALISED** - A successful WSAStartup call must occur before using this function.

**WSAEFAULT** - The Windows Sockets implementation was unable to allocate needed resources for its internal operations, or the readfds, writefds, exceptfds, or timeval parameters are not part of the user address space.

**WSAENETDOWN** - The network subsystem has failed.

**WSAEINVAL** - The time-out value is not valid, or all three descriptor parameters were null.

**WSAEINTR** - A blocking Windows Socket 1.1 call was canceled through WSACancelBlockingCall.

**WSAEINPROGRESS** - A blocking Windows Sockets 1.1 call is in progress, or the service provider is still processing a callback function.

**WSAENOTSOCK** - One of the descriptor sets contains an entry that is not a socket.

Comment: Asker appears to be using winsock, in which case `select()` won't set `errno`, but returns an error via `WSAGetLastError()` instead.